# Разница между списочным и key (в данном примере)

Tags: python

Скажите, почему в этом примере `max` и `key=lambda x: x % 2 != 0` выводит не максимальный нечетный элемент в списке?

Ввод:

```
6
100
8
33
45
19
90
```

Программа:

```
n = int(input())
k = []

for i in range(n):
    num = int(input())
    k.append(num)

print(k)
even = max(k, key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0) # то есть максимальный четный элемент списка
odd = max(k, key=lambda x: x % 2 != 0) # максимальный нечетный элемент списка (но выводит 33, вместо 45)

print(even)
print(odd)
```

Должно получиться 100 и 45, но выводит 100 и 33. Почему?

Comment: Потому что в этом коде и речи нет о чётности/нечётности чисел. Вы просто сравниваете элементы по их остатку от деления на 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

потому что вы при поиске превращаете все числа в `True` / `False`, которые в Python представлены числами `1` / `0`, и, соответственно, всегда получаете первое число удовлетворяющее условию (`True`).

Т.е. в случае с `max(k, key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)` вы ищете максимум в следующем списке **по второму элементу кортежа**:

```
In [77]: print([(x, x%2==0) for x in k])
[(6, True), (100, True), (8, True), (33, False), (45, False), (19, False), (90, True)]
```

Первое `True` (четное) - `6` - его вы и получаете, тоже самое с нечетными - вы получаете первое нечетное из списка - `33`

---

Можно слегка исправить ваше решение:

```
In [71]: from math import inf

In [72]: max(k, key=lambda x: x if x % 2 == 0 else -inf)
Out[72]: 100
```

для нечетных:

```
In [73]: max(k, key=lambda x: x if x % 2 != 0 else -inf)
Out[73]: 45
```

**Но лучше сделать так** - это более явная и понятная форма:

```
In [74]: max(x for x in k if x%2==0)
Out[74]: 100

In [75]: max(x for x in k if x%2!=0)
Out[75]: 45
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому, что эта программа выводит 2 числа:

- **первое** из четных чисел,
- **первое** из нечетных чисел.

---

*Объяснение:*

Выражение `key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0` значит, что для всякого числа `x`сначала вычислится остаток после деления двумя (`x % 2`), затем он сравнивается с нулем (`== 0`), чем получится `True` для четных и `False` для нечетных чисел.

Сравнивая эти значения (`True` и `False`), `True` более `False`, значит, максимом будет первое четное число.

(Подобным способом для выражения `key=lambda x: x % 2 != 0` — здесь «выигрывает» первое *нечетное* число.)

---

*Исправление:*

Вы не хотите *изменить ключ* для вычисления максима, вы хотите *фильтровать* применением этой ламбда-функции — значит, правильные команды будут

```
even = max(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, k))
odd  = max(filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, k))
```

Comment: Да, вот фильтр в данном случае абсолютно соответствует постановке задачи